# Android equivalents to [event allTouches] and event.timestamp?

Tags: android, multi-touch, equivalent

I was wondering, does anyone know what are the Android equivalents to [event allTouches] and event.timestamp found in iOS?  I am working on a multi-touch gesture recognizer for Android, and would like to know what are Android's equivalents to those iOS calls.

Comment: It might help if you explained exactly what you're trying to get, for those not versed in iOS...

Comment: Basically, `[event allTouches]` returns an array of all the touches on the screen.  `event.timestamp` is the time when a touch has began, ended, or moved.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your best bet is to read the [Android SDK documents](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html). Essentially, touches in Android are managed by setting an `OnTouchListener` to a view, and managing from there. The OnTouchListener has a single function, `OnTouchEvent`, which follows the following format:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
```

Inside the [`MotionEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html), there is data on every finger placed. There are things like `getX(int )`, `getY(int )` and `getPointerId(int )`. Also, the status is listed. Anything you want to do you can do from that.

Comment: Okay, this answers my question about getting the different pointers on the screen, however, how do I get a timestamp on when a touch has began, ended, or moved?

Comment: You don't get a timestamp for free, what you have to do is keep track of your own timestamp when you first detect the `POINTER_DOWN` action.